# Colouring code parts of multiline variable in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a variable `var`.  Want to print the lines after `Code:` in `blue` (but with the line specifying `Code:` removed), whilst the rest is printed in `green`.  Am using a bash script that calls awk to do the variable processing running ubuntu.

```
sgr="$( tput sgr0 )"
grn="$( tput bold; tput setaf 34 )"
blu="$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )"

var="
 Description
 Code:
  for i in {1..72..1}; do shft+=\" \"; done
 
 Details"

printf '%s\n' "$var"  \
 | awk -v kb="$blu" -v kg="$grn" -v rst="$sgr"  \
     '{ codefound = 0
        fm="%s%s%s\n"
        if (codefound) { printf(fm, kb, $0, rst) }
        else { printf(fm, kg, $0, rst) }
      }'
```

How can one define the colours in `awk` itself ?

I want to produce the following (the # used to describe the foreground colour of the text):

```
 Description  # green
   for i in {1..72..1}; do shft+=" "; done  # blue
 
 Details  # green
```

Comment: do you know about [`vim` syntax highlighting](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html) if you are using vim to view your code.

Comment: Please don't multi-post - https://stackoverflow.com/q/75425479/1745001.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based heavily on the answer at [using-awk-to-color-the-output-in-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64034385/using-awk-to-color-the-output-in-bash/64046525#64046525), this might be what you want for this and any similar situations where you need to change, potentially multiple, foreground and/or background colors:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("BLACK RED GREEN YELLOW BLUE MAGENTA CYAN WHITE",tputColors)
    for (i in tputColors) {
        colorName = tputColors[i]
        colorNr = i-1

        cmd = "tput setaf " colorNr
        fgEscSeq[colorName] = ( (cmd | getline escSeq) > 0 ? escSeq : "<" colorName ">" )
        close(cmd)

        cmd = "tput setab " colorNr
        bgEscSeq[colorName] = ( (cmd | getline escSeq) > 0 ? escSeq : "<" colorName ">" )
        close(cmd)
    }

    cmd = "tput sgr0"
    colorOff = ( (cmd | getline escSeq) > 0 ? escSeq : "<sgr0>" )
    close(cmd)

    fgColor = dfltFgColor = "GREEN"
}

/Code:/ { fgColor = "BLUE"; next }
!NF { fgColor = dfltFgColor }
{ print fgEscSeq[fgColor] $0 colorOff }
```

[image]

If you'd rather not use `tput` to define colors then see [searching-and-coloring-lines-by-awk-or-other-method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/669111/searching-and-coloring-lines-by-awk-or-other-method/669122#669122) for how to use escape sequences instead.

Comment: I really want to use specific numeric values for the colours `sgr="$( tput sgr0 )" ; wht="$( tput bold; tput setaf 15 )" ; blu="$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )"`.

Comment: Then also add that to your question. Again, don't add information in comments where it could be missed.

Answer (score 2):

To colorizing a line with ANSI escape codes in awk say a line containing string "WORD", you can do:

```
printf '%s\n' "$var" |
awk '
BEGIN{
       blue ="\033[1;44m"
       rst  ="\033[0m"
}
/WORD/{ $0=blue $0 rst }1'
```

The code for your need would be:

```
printf '%s\n' "$var" |
awk '
BEGIN{
       green ="\033[1;42m"  #default output color
       blue  ="\033[1;44m"
       rst   ="\033[0m"
}
/Code:$/  { Clr=1; next }  # active the blue colored ouptut
/Details$/{ Clr=0 }        # disable the blue colored output

{ print (Clr? blue : green) $0 rst }'
```

see [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Comment: Not all devices use ANSI codes, that's the reason why `tput` and the related `termcap`/`terminfo` exist.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `awk` for this, I would just use `sed` and `printf`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

var="
 Description
 Code:
  for i in {1..72..1}; do shft+=' '; done
 
 Details"

sgr="$( tput sgr0 )"
grn="$( tput bold; tput setaf 34 )"
blu="$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )"

printf "%s" "$grn"; sed -E "s/Code:/$blu/; s/^( *Details.*)/${grn}\1${sgr}/" <<<"$var";
```

This produces:

[image: Screenshot of the terminal showing the output of the command in color]

If you insist on `awk`, something like this would work:

```
#!/bin/bash
var="
 Description
 Code:
  for i in {1..72..1}; do shft+=' '; done

 Details"

sgr="$( tput sgr0 )"
grn="$( tput bold; tput setaf 34 )"
blu="$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )"

awk -v sgr="$( tput sgr0 )" \
    -v grn="$( tput bold; tput setaf 34 )" \
    -v blu="$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )" \
'BEGIN{ printf "%s", grn }
{
  if(/Code:/){ printf "%s", blu }
  else if(/Details/){ printf "%s%s%s\n",grn, $0, sgr }
  else { print }
}' <<<"$var";
```

Comment: For the awk solution, it still prints `Code:`.  I also want to have blue foreground on the consecutive lines until a blank line occurs.

Comment: One does not match for `Details`,   Once one gets the first blank line, one changes to green colour, until another match for `Code:`.

Comment: @Gibran please add that information to your question, don't add it as a comment where it can be missed.

Comment: @Gibran the awk one doesn't print `Code:`, are you _sure_ you copied it exactly? Can your file have Windows line endings perhaps? And the simpler one does match `Details`, at least on my machine, so again, maybe Windows line endings?

Comment: @terdon the OP isn't saying your code doesn't match `Details`, they're saying it does match `Details` but it shouldn't, it should match an empty line.