# Handling multiple colour declarations for colour printing

Tags: awk

I want to simplify the task of colour printing a multiline variable using `awk`.

```
var="
Blu:
  Some text in blue here
  Some more blue text

Grn:
  Some green text here
  More green text"

awk \
  'BEGIN {
     "tput sgr0" |& getline sgr
     "tput bold; tput setaf 15"  |& getline wht
     "tput bold; tput setaf 34"  |& getline grn
     "tput bold; tput setaf 39"  |& getline blu
     "tput bold; tput setaf 11"  |& getline ylw
     "tput bold; tput setaf 196" |& getline red
     "tput bold; tput setaf 214" |& getline amb

     "tput bold; tput setaf 51"  |& getline cyn
     "tput bold; tput setaf 201" |& getline mgn
   }
   
   /Wht:$/ { kw=1 ; next }
   /Grn:$/ { kg=1 ; next }
   /Blu:$/ { kb=1 ; next }
   /Ylw:$/ { ky=1 ; next }
   /Red:$/ { kr=1 ; next }
   /Amb:$/ { ka=1 ; next }
   /Cyn:$/ { kc=1 ; next }
   /Mgn:$/ { km=1 ; next }

   !NF { kw=0 ; kg=0 ; kb=0 ; ky=0 ; kr=0 ; ka=0 ; kc=0 ; km=0
         next }
   kw { printf("%s%s%s\n", wht, $0, sgr) }
   kb { printf("%s%s%s\n", blu, $0, sgr) }
   ky { printf("%s%s%s\n", ylw, $0, sgr) }
   kr { printf("%s%s%s\n", red, $0, sgr) }
   ka { printf("%s%s%s\n", amb, $0, sgr) }
   kc { printf("%s%s%s\n", cyn, $0, sgr) }
   km { printf("%s%s%s\n", mgn, $0, sgr) }
  ' <<< "$var"
```

Comment: This is about handling the variable so that the lines get coloured according to lines starting with `Wht:`, `Grn:`, `Blu:` etc. With eight different colours using the matching command `kw { printf("%s%s%s\n", wht, $0, sgr) }` for all the different colours looked tedious. Perhaps the code could be simplified.

Comment: I already showed you how to simplify it in my answer to your last question - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/735173/133219. Just do what I show there - populate an array of colors, set a `fgColor` variable when your regexp matches, then print it with $0. You could even use exactly the strings `Wht:`, et.c as the array indices and then you don't have to pattern-match any of them, just use the string from the input as the index.

Comment: The problem with that is your use of `colorNr`.  I have specific values for the colour described in my code.

Comment: Then just tweak my answer to use your specific numbers,, you don't need to change the approach. I posted an answer.

Comment: Would I put the numbers in an array, then call the corresponding array index?

Comment: You'd do exactly what I show in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/735256/133219).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735162/colouring-code-parts-of-multiline-variable-in-awk/735173#735173) to your previous question and factoring in the requirements from your previous question plus what your current code is trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

var="
Blu:
  Some text in blue here
  Some more blue text

Grn:
  Some green text here
  More green text"

awk '
    BEGIN {
        n = split("Wht 15 Grn 34 Blu 39 Ylw 11 Red 196 Amb 214 Cyn 51 Mgn 201",tputColors)
        for ( i=1; i<n; i+=2 ) {
            colorName = tputColors[i] ":"
            colorNr = tputColors[i+1]

            cmd = "tput setaf " colorNr
            fgEscSeq[colorName] = ( (cmd | getline escSeq) > 0 ? escSeq : "<" colorName ">" )
            close(cmd)
        }

        cmd = "tput sgr0"
        colorOff = ( (cmd | getline escSeq) > 0 ? escSeq : "<sgr0>" )
        close(cmd)

        fgColor = dfltFgColor = "Grn:"
    }

    /^[[:alpha:]]+:/ && ($1 in fgEscSeq) { fgColor = $1; next }
    !NF { fgColor = dfltFgColor; next }
    { print fgEscSeq[fgColor] $0 colorOff }
' <<< "$var"
```

The result of calling `tput` with the numbers you're using doesn't generate any colors on my terminal so I can't show it working but presumably it'll work on your terminal. Here's the output showing the escape sequences that are produced:

```
$ ./tst.sh | cat -v
^[[339m  Some text in blue here^[(B^[[m
^[[339m  Some more blue text^[(B^[[m
^[[334m  Some green text here^[(B^[[m
^[[334m  More green text^[(B^[[m
```

By the way, if you're ever considering using `getline` make sure to read and fully understand http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline to know when and how to use it correctly. In your code you're calling it using a co-process which is unnecessarily GNU-specific and you're calling it in a way that'd just silently populate the wrong colors if it failed and you aren't closing the pipes or killing the processes you're spinning off until the script ends, see my code for the correct and portable way to call it.

Comment: I see you put the modified answer here, where you use the same array `tputColors`.  Really helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to clearly show how minimal the changes are from [my previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/735173/133219) - just provide different specific numbers for `tput` and then populate `fgColor` whenever you find one of the target color names in the input. But the approach and most of the code is exactly the same.

Comment: Do you use `"<" colorName ">"` to signify a problem ?

Comment: Yes I do. That way if you see a line printed you expect to be colored and instead just has `<Red>` or similar at the start of it you'll know the getline failed and which color it was trying to read when it failed. You could of course do `if ( ( cmd | getline ... ) > 0 ) { success stuff } else { report fail }` instead (or additionally), what I wrote was just what IMO is the minimal code to flag a getline failure in some way,

Comment: The link the freeshell does not exist.

Comment: It does exist, the sites apparently just down at the moment.

Comment: I want to understand the idea of coprocess.  Where does a coprocess come in, is it when using `(...)`.

Comment: Coprocesses have nothing to do with `(...)`, they are to do with `|&`, and they're a method of 2-way inter process communication in GNU awk. They (and everything else you might want to know about awk) are described in the book Effecive AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins which I referred you to at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735337/array-index-in-awk#comment1396119_735337. The author of that book has graciously made it available for reference so you can see the relevant section at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline_002fCoprocess but buy the book

Comment: It should be equivalent to `2>&1 |`, that generates both `stdout` and `stderr` to `getline`.  Should one use `cmd | getline outp` or is `cmd 2>&1 | getline outp` better?

Comment: That's a few times now you've said something **should be** something else when it simply isn't. Not sure if that's just a language thing or someone's telling you something wrong or something else. In this case, you're mixing up shell and awk syntax, there is no `2>&1` in awk, that's a shell construct. Ask a new question about whatever it is you're now trying to do.

Comment: That's what my understanding is.  Which could be wrong.