# Array index in awk

Tags: awk

I have tho following awk code, that makes the array `kaggr` and then stores values in `knam` and `knum`.  Have the impression that the loop should not start from `1`, but from `0`, but `for ( i=1; i<n; i+=2 )` seems to work.  Awk arrays should start from index `0`, so are things working when starting from `1` ?

```
awk 'BEGIN { kl=0
       "tput sgr0" |& getline rst
       ks = "Wht 15 Grn 34 Blu 39 Ylw 11 Red 196 Amb 214"
       n = split(ks, kaggr)
       for ( i=1; i<n; i+=2 ) {
         knam = kaggr[i] ":"
         knum = kaggr[i+1]
        }
     }
```

Comment: Awk arrays can have any index you feel like: negative integer, float, string (including the empty string). All indexes are held as text strings. The integer ones need not even be consecutive: X[-4], X[67], X[log(5.3)] and X["Joe"] constitute a valid 4-entry array. However, the **split** and **asort** functions *create* arrays that index consecutively from 1 up, and **substr** uses 1-based indexing. Reading an undeclared array element creates it as a null string.

Comment: Regarding `Awk arrays should start from index 0` - fields, generated arrays, and strings in awk all start from position 1, not 0, as stated in every awk man page, book, etc. From this and your other code using lots of `[s]printf`s I think you're assuming awk is C-like in areas where it isn't. I'd recommend you get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn about awk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you split a string with `split()` in `awk`, you get an array whose indexes start at `1`.

From [the documentation on a BSD system](http://man.openbsd.org/awk#split):

> `split(s, a, fs)`
> Splits the string `s` into array elements `a[1]`, `a[2]`, ..., `a[n]` and returns `n`.

To access the elements of the array in pairs, you should therefore loop from `1` to `n - 1` in steps of 2 and access elements `i` and `i+1` in each iteration.

```c
n = split(string, a)
for (i = 1; i <= n - 1; i += 2) {
    # use a[i] and a[i+1]
}
```

Obviously, `i <= n - 1` is the same as `i < n`, so your loop is correct.