# Unpivoting Delimited String to get the parent child relationship

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a scenario where in need to unpivot the data to achieve the parent child relationship.
My source data is as below:

**Key_Col|Hierarchy**

1|a,b,c,d

2|a,b,c,d,e

My Expected Output below:

| Key Col | Child | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | d | c |
| 1 | c | b |
| 1 | b | a |
| 1 | a | null |
| 2 | e | d |
| 2 | d | c |
| 2 | c | b |
| 2 | b | a |
| 2 | a | null |

Could you please let me know how can I achieve this via a bash script?

Script I used is:

```
Var="1|a,b,c,d";
for i in $Var
do
 Key=`echo $i |cut -d'|' -f1`
 Hierarchy=`echo $i |cut -d'|' -f2`
 Delim_Count=`echo ${Hierarchy} |awk -F',' '{ print NF-1 }'`
 for (( c=$Delim_Count+1; c>=1; c-- ))
 do
   Parent=`echo ${Hierarchy} |cut -d',' -f$c`
   Prev=`expr $c - 1`
   if [ $Prev -ne 0 ]; then
    Child=`echo ${Hierarchy} |cut -d',' -f${Prev}`
    echo "${Key}|${Parent}|${Child}"
   else
    echo "${Key}|${Parent}|"
   fi
 done
done
```

But the issue is, If there are more than 100 lines, the script is taking ages to complete.

Comment: Hmmm, seems you're asking to `left-pad` your missing values ;-). Glad to see you tackling the project yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like these are usually easier to do with a language made for processing text or structured data. Below is a solution using the standard text-processing utility `awk` and one using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`), a tool specifically used for processing structured data (your data looks like CSV).

---

With `awk`:

```bash
$ cat file
Key_Col|Hierarchy
1|a,b,c,d
2|a,b,c,d,e
```

```bash
$ awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="|" } NR == 1 { print $1, "Child", "Parent"; next } { n=split($2,a,","); a[0]="null"; for (i=n;i>0;i--) print $1,a[i],a[i-1] }' file
Key_Col|Child|Parent
1|d|c
1|c|b
1|b|a
1|a|null
2|e|d
2|d|c
2|c|b
2|b|a
2|a|null
```

The `awk` code above reads each input line as a set of `|`-delimited fields. It splits the second field on the commas into the array `a`.  The zeroth element of the array is set to the string `null` ([`split()` creates an array whose first index is 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735337/array-index-in-awk), so we know we can use index 0 without overwriting data). We then iterate from the end of the array to the start, outputting the first field's value with the current array element and the preceding element in the array.  When we reach the last iteration, our loop variable will have the value 1, which causes `a[1]` and `a[0]` (`null`) to be printed.

The first line of input, which contains a header, is treated differently. Instead of splitting etc., the code prints three fields: the first field from the input and one field each for the strings `Child` and `Parent`. The conditional `NR==1` block does this.

The `awk` code, reformatted for readability:

```c
BEGIN {
    OFS = FS = "|"
}

NR == 1 {
    print $1, "Child", "Parent"
    next
}

{
    n = split($2, a, ",")
    a[0] = "null"
    for (i = n; i > 0; i--)
        print $1, a[i], a[i-1]
}
```

---

Since the input looks like CSV, it may be safer to use a CSV-aware tool to process it. Miller (`mlr`) is such a tool:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --fs pipe put -q 'm=splitnv($Hierarchy,","); m[0]="null"; for (var i=length(m)-1;i>0;i-=1) { emit {"Key_Col": $Key_Col, "Child": m[i], "Parent": m[i-1] } }' file
Key_Col|Child|Parent
1|d|c
1|c|b
1|b|a
1|a|null
2|e|d
2|d|c
2|c|b
2|b|a
2|a|null
```

The Miller `put` expression follows the same outline as the above `awk` code, but without having to deal with the headers as a special case since Miller knows how to read and use these:

```
m = splitnv($Hierarchy, ",")
m[0] = "null"

for (var i = length(m) - 1; i > 0; i -= 1) {
    emit {
        "Key_Col": $Key_Col,
        "Child": m[i],
        "Parent": m[i-1]
    }
}
```

Miller allows us to produce the result in many different forms by adjusting the options before the `put` sub-command.

Pretty-printed "barred" output:

```bash
$ mlr --c2p --barred --ifs pipe put ...as above...
+---------+-------+--------+
| Key_Col | Child | Parent |
+---------+-------+--------+
| 1       | d     | c      |
| 1       | c     | b      |
| 1       | b     | a      |
| 1       | a     | null   |
| 2       | e     | d      |
| 2       | d     | c      |
| 2       | c     | b      |
| 2       | b     | a      |
| 2       | a     | null   |
+---------+-------+--------+
```

JSON:

```bash
$ mlr --c2j --ifs pipe put ...as above...
{ "Key_Col": 1, "Child": "d", "Parent": "c" }
{ "Key_Col": 1, "Child": "c", "Parent": "b" }
{ "Key_Col": 1, "Child": "b", "Parent": "a" }
{ "Key_Col": 1, "Child": "a", "Parent": "null" }
{ "Key_Col": 2, "Child": "e", "Parent": "d" }
{ "Key_Col": 2, "Child": "d", "Parent": "c" }
{ "Key_Col": 2, "Child": "c", "Parent": "b" }
{ "Key_Col": 2, "Child": "b", "Parent": "a" }
{ "Key_Col": 2, "Child": "a", "Parent": "null" }
```

(etc.)

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda. I appreciate the answer and the thorough explanation. Unfortunately we can't use Miller as our application is on Linux.

Comment: @MAK33 I'm using Miller on various Linux distributions daily, so I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. In any case, you have the `awk` code too.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a; for lines() {.split("|") andthen @a.push: .[0] => ("null".Slip, .[1].split(",").Slip) };  \
            put .invert.invert.join("\n") for [Z=>] @a.map(*.key), @a.map(*.value.rotor(2 => -1) );'   file
```

Above is an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Briefly, an array is declared in the first statement. In the second statement `lines()` are read into an "array-of-hashes", via first `split`ting first on `|` bar to get the key, then splitting on `,` comma for the values. A `"null"` is added to the beginning of each series of values. Since Raku doesn't auto-flatten array elements (thankfully), flattening is accomplished with calls to `.Slip`. In the final statement, the "null"-padded values are `rotor`ed with overlap, each line's key and values are `[Z=>]` zipped into pairs, `invert`ed twice to expand the keys to each associated value, then printed with either `say` or `put`.

Sample Input:

```
1|a,b,c,d
2|a,b,c,d,e
3|a,b,c
```

Sample Output (non-reversed columns):

```
1   null a
1   a b
1   b c
1   c d
2   null a
2   a b
2   b c
2   c d
2   d e
3   null a
3   a b
3   b c
```

If you need to handle the header line, a simple way to do so is add a call to `.skip` after `lines` (defaults to skipping one line), then add back a header of your choice with `say()`.

Finally, the OP's requirement is actually reverse the order of the columns, which can be accomplished by interposing a call to `.reverse` in the last statement, writing the final preparation of `@a.map(*.value.rotor(2 => -1)` as `@a.map(*.value.reverse.rotor(2 => -1)`.

Sample Output (reversed columns):

```
1   d c
1   c b
1   b a
1   a null
2   e d
2   d c
2   c b
2   b a
2   a null
3   c b
3   b a
3   a null
```

https://raku.org