# Processing a multiline variable line by line within a bash function

Tags: bash, function

Is it possible to process a multiline variable in a bash function?  Suppose I have a function `theone` and I pass a multiline variable to it.

```
var="
This
is a 
multiline
variable"

theone "$var"
```

I want to colour specific lines from `var` according to some matching pattern without using `awk` or `sed`.

Comment: Be precise/concise about what do you want to do with this multi-line sample

Comment: Seems like you have lot of responses here or on stackoverflow about this topic, mostly based on awk. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735367/line-colouring-fails-for-syp-and-code
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735244/handling-multiple-colour-declarations-for-colour-printing
Whats wrong with those responses?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64034385/using-awk-to-color-the-output-in-bash/64046525#64046525

Comment: There is nothing wrong.  But as the number and length of awk commands increasing, I started putting everything in separate awk files.  One problem with awk files is the difficulty of integrating different implementations in a single awk file.  Furthermore, multiple branching make awk files inefficient because the tests are done for every line being read.

Answer (score 0):

##### As a starter:

```
#!/bin/bash

theone() {
    printf -- '%s\n' "$var" | while IFS= read -r line; do
        tput setaf $((++c))
        echo "$line"
        ((c==8)) && c=0
    done
    tput sgr0
}

theone "$var"
```

[image]

Comment: So the trick is using `printf '%s\n'` upon the variable.

Comment: I do get `--` getting printed though.

Comment: What does `IFS=` default to?  Surely not on space, right?

Comment: Fixed the place of _end of parameters_ aka `--`. The `while IFS= read -r` is the recommended robust/reliable way to read line by line http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F001.How_can_I_read_a_file_.28data_stream.2C_variable.29_line-by-line_.28and.2For_field-by-field.29.3F

Comment: The `printf` is just a better and more portable way to write `echo`